# JQuery Bootstrap MultiSelect not working when using Fully Qualified Domain Name

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, bootstrap-4

I am running IIS 7, ASP.Net 4.7 and C#.

When I run my page as

```
https://Name/RBAC_Management.aspx
```

it works correctly and the Bootstrap Multiselect works.

When I use

```
https://Name.domain.net/RBAC_Management.aspx
```

everything works as normal except the Bootstrap Multiselect does not change the lists to drop downs

```
   function multiBox() {
            var checkBox = $('[id*="multichkbx"]');
            if (checkBox != null)
            {
                $('[id*="multichkbx"]').multiselect
                    ({
                        includeSelectAllOption: true,
                        buttonWidth: 250,
                        nonSelectedText: 'None Selected',
                        enableFiltering: true,
                        enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
                        maxHeight: 350
                    });
            }
        };
```

This normally creates a dropdown list box similar to what you see here, https://www.sitepoint.com/13-jquery-selectboxdrop-down-plugins/

But if the jquery does not run or find something than it will just show up as a list.

Comment: are you running into cors issues?

Comment: I took a look at the IE Debugger in Dev tools and I see that I am getting this error message up loading with the FQDN. - Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener'  I am using jQuery 3.4.1 and also have the meta data set to <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />. One thing I noticed, the site is in Local Intranet zone when not using the FQDN and in the Trusted Zone when using the FQDN. So I lowered the security but had the same result.

Comment: Looks like I am being forced to use IE 8 Enterprise Mode when switching to Trusted Zone - HTML1122: Internet Explorer is running in Enterprise Mode emulating IE8.

Comment: Turned off Enterprise Mode and the JQuery error is gone, but it still acts the same. I tried lowering the security in that zone as well. Any ideas?

Comment: did you try to use another browser? I tried your jquery and its working well in chrome and edge. please share your included bootstrap code. like `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-2.3.2.min.js"></script>` open browser and press f12 and check console does it sow any error.

Comment: I tried it Chrome and Firefox and both seem to run the code but it is not running correctly. Could be a CSS issue with that, but I would say that both Name and Name.Domain.Net work the same.

Comment: <link href="/Styles/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/Styles/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap-multiselect.min.js"></script>

Comment: I tried it from one of my servers that does not have a bunch of security policies and it seems to work correctly. I am going to try and have the GPO admins add my site to the Local Intranet sites list to see if that will make a difference.

Comment: does it works after adding into Local Intranet sites?

Comment: Still waiting on the admins to complete the change. I will send an update as soon as it is completed.

Comment: That did not resolve the issue but I found that the Enterprise Mode was still coming by policy on even though I had turned it off. With Enterprise Mode off everything is working correctly. Thanks for the responses.